# Mathematics not showing up in Accounts section of profile

Tags: support, user-accounts

Typically I can click my user name and view the accounts I have for the various SE sites. Just noticed that for some reason my mathematics account isn't listed. Is this the same for others? Not a big deal, it's just odd that it's missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accounts are only linked if they have at least 1 credential in common.

To resolve this

- visit the accounts tab on your user profile and scroll to the bottom
- click the "clear all associations" button
- click the "associate" button